# If $x$ is real find the maximum possible value of $10^x-100^x$

Tags: calculus, optimization, exponential-function, nonlinear-optimization, maxima-minima

According to the person who gave this question it apparently has something to do with the range of a quadratic expression. But I can't see the connection with a quadratic equation.

So I tried to solve this by finding the maxima of the expression.

But I don't know how to do it as it's an exponential function.
All I can infer from this is that $x$ must be negative.

Comment: It does have something to do with quadratics if you realise that 100 is $10^2$

Comment: @MilesB now that you say it, it's so obvious why didn't I think of it!

Comment: I didn't see it imediately.  but I did see $10^x - 100^x = 10^x(1- 10^x)$ immediately. Then I have to think of what the max/min of $a(1-a)$ is in general.

Comment: We will now have zillions of answers elaborating on MilesB's hint...

Comment: Yes, @zwim , but my answer below is the most concise!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$F(x)=10^x-100^x=10^x(1-10^x)$$

Let $$f(a)=a(1-a)$$
$$f'(a)=1-2a$$
the maximum of $ f(a)  $ is $$ f(\frac 12)=\frac 14.$$

Thus, the maximum of $ F(x) $ is $ \frac 14 $ attained for $ x$ such that

$$10^x=\frac 12 = e^{x\ln(10)}$$

Comment: Or $$a(1-a)=\dfrac14-\left(a-\dfrac12\right)^2$$

Comment: I realise that my mistake was that I was differentiating $10^x-100^x$ directly.

Comment: Not necessarily terrible... $\ln(10)*10^x - \ln(100)*100^x = 0$ means $\ln(10)10^x = \ln(100)100^x$ means $\frac {\ln 10}{\ln 100} =\frac {100^x}{10^x}=(\frac {100}{10})^x$ means $\log_{100} 10 = 10^x$ means $\frac 12 = 10^x$ means $x =\log_{10} \frac 12$.

Comment: @fleablood There was actually a mistake in my differentiation.

Answer (score 1):

$10^x - 100^x = 10^x -(10^2)^x = 10^x - (10^x)^2$

Let $y = 10^x$ then $10^x - 100^x = y - y^2$.

To find the maximum of that... well, use calculus.  $f(y) = y-y^2$ so $f'(y) = 1-2y=0 \implies y=\frac 12$ so the maximum value is $y = \frac 12$.

So $y = 10^x = \frac 12$

And $x =\log_{10} \frac 12 = -\log_{10} 2$.

Answer (score 1):

The point being made here is that $100^x = (10^x)^2$ - so your expression is really
$$10^x - (10^x)^2$$
or, if we let $y=10^x$ we get
$$y-y^2$$
which is just a quadratic, which you can maximize - though you do have to note that the range of possible $y$ is just positive real numbers, though that's okay because $y-y^2$ is maximized with a value of $1/4$ at $y=1/2$ (i.e. when $x = \log_{10}(1/2)$).

Of course, the usual calculus method works too - if you let $f(x)=10^x-100^x$ and differentiate you get $f'(x)=\ln(10)10^x-\ln(100)100^x$. Setting this to zero and moving things around gives
$$\ln(10)10^x = \ln(100)100^x.$$
You could then solve this by taking a logarithm of both sides, which gives
$$\ln(\ln(10))+\ln(10)x = \ln(\ln(100)) + \ln(100)x$$
which is then a linear equation that solves as
$$x=\frac{\ln(\ln(100))-\ln(\ln(10))}{\ln(10)-\ln(100)}$$
which is equal to $\log_{10}(1/2)$ if you simplify - although hopefully if you get that far in simplifying, you would realize that $100=10^2$ at some point! This method works even when there's no special relationship between the bases.

Answer (score 0):

Let $t=10^x$.  Then the expression to be maximised is (for $t>0$): $$t-t^2$$
$$ = \frac14 -(\frac12 - t)^2$$ which clearly has a maximum of $\frac14$

Comment: Why is it obvious that the maximum is $\frac{1}{4}$?

Comment: @Sujal Motagi - because we have an expression that takes the form $\frac14-A^2$, where $A^2$ is a square, so zero or positive, so the expression will be maximised when A is zero.

Answer (score 0):

@MilesB pointed out that I can turn this into a quadratic by substituting $10^x$  with something else.

Let $t=10^x$.

The given expression becomes,
$$-t^2+t$$

Now we can find the maxima by using a special property of quadratic functions.
A function $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ where $a$ is negative is maximum at $x=\frac{-b}{2a}$

So the maximum of $-t^2+t$ is at $t=\frac{1}{2}$. So the maximum possible value of the given expression is
$$\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\frac{1}{2}$$
$$=\boxed{\frac{1}{4}}$$

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively:

$f(x) = 10^x - 100^x$

$f'(x) = \ln 10*10^x - \ln 100* 100^x$.

$f'(x) = 0$ means

$\ln 10*10^x - \ln 100* 100^x=0$ means

$\ln 10*10^x =\ln 100* 100^x$

$\frac {\ln 10}{\ln 100} = \frac {100^x}{10^x}$

LHS is $\log_{100} 10 = \frac 1{\log_{10} 100} = \frac 12$ and RHS is $(\frac {100}{10})^x = 10^x$.

So $10^x =\frac 12$ and $x = \log_{10} \frac 12$.